# Hover on image a

Tags: image, hover, joomla2.5

I am making a website in Joomla.

And on my front page I have some images, which are links.

I want these images a's to get a slightly green effect, like opacity + green and stil have the original images below.

Is this possible to do with only css?

I can get the opacity to work, but not the green color.

Hope some one can help me.

[Here is my site. it is the the small images under "Referencer" and "Nyheder"](http://martinehlers.dk)

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with CSS. The main trick is that the links currently aren't surrounding the img block because their display type is inline.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="greenish"><img src="..." /></a>
```

This is the CSS you need:

```
a.greenish { 
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
a.greenish img { 
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Adjust green and opacity to taste, obviously.

See this [lovely jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKXmy/3/) for an example. Note that this includes addition CSS in case you only want it to turn green when hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do what you want with pure CSS easily. There is no "overlay" in CSS. You can manipulate the background color/opacity, but the image would always be on top of that so it would not achieve the effect you want.

What you will need to do is to make the image the background of the A, then change the background do a similar image with the effect already applied. The images are small so you could easily make them sprites with the over look all in the same image. I did exactly this on the social icons at the top of my company website - http://www.bnrbranding.com/